# Faster search for files in Netbeans

Tags: search, netbeans, find

Is there an existing plugin or tweak that speeds up the "Go To File" search in Netbeans ? Compared to Eclipse, Netbeans search is way too slow specially if one has multiple large size projects.

I know I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for "Go To Type" but often I need to search for other file types like XMLs, property files etc. across thousands of files in multiple projects.

I installed the Quick Search plugin but even that doesn't search for non Java file types.

Comment: Please check wiki netbeans: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score 169):

You can focus on the Project Tree and simply type the file name which you want to looking for. Press Up/Down to select if more than one file match your search.

Or use keyboard shortcut to open the search file form:

- **Windows/Linux**:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

- **Mac OS**:

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: unluckily the trick of simply typing only works when a file is already visible eg. its folder/package tree is open... But great about the A+S+O!!!

Comment: and all these people telling us to download a plugin when the functionality is already built in netbeans, tsc tsc tsc, must be carefull these days otherwise you'll bloat your IDE with unecessary plugins

Answer (score 9):

The best way to search and open file in netbeans - 
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and type file name you are looking for, it will search in current projects and list matching files

Answer (score 5):

why not right click on the project and click 'find'?

Answer (score 4):

I can only recommend using the Open File Fast plugin 
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16495/open-file-fast

Comment: Just a bump.. is this still the case or is the "native" netbeans seach now good enough?

Answer (score 2):

How to quickly find a file/files in netbeans. Maybe for someone it will be helpful.

1. In Netbeans projects files view select some directory where you want to look for the file.
2. Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to show the finder dialog
3. Pass your file name into 'file name patterns' input
4. In options set only 'Regular expression'
5. The 'Containing text' input has to be empty

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16495/open-file-fast

Find file fast will your solution for find file faster just like sublime..
using the shortcut alt+shift+o

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [recent file list plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/31677/recent-file-list)

This plugin is not as powerful as the intellij but to simulate the same behavior  (open the recent files with ctrl+E):

After install the plugin assign the Ctrl+E shortcut to the "Recent Files" action: `Tools->Options->Keymap->Search "Recent Files" and assign Ctrl+E shortcut`

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to search by file name/pattern, then I suggest plugin "Quick File Search" http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/70267

Answer (score -3):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + H.`

On the screen appear option `scope`. Click on this text-box and choose the project you want to find needed text snippets, or you can find all of the projects. I am using Netbeans 8.1 Best regard !