# Switching between netbeans files by name

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

Is there a way in Netbeans, or a plugin, that enables switching between files by name? E.g. entering the name, or part of the name, of the file, and getting a dynamically narrowed list of matching files?

I'd like to reproduce the Emacs behavior of C-x b with ido flex-matching mode on, but even something without fuzzy matching would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the "**Go to File...**" feature accessible with `SHIFT + ALT + O`

It opens a box where you can search for a file allowing to search by name with wilcards.

EDIT: Found this plugin [Open File Fast](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16495/open-file-fast) on another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994297/1606729)

Comment: That's quite nice. No fuzzy matching, but useful nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeB : Added a Netbeans plugin that might interest you